# Ajax sends data and gets response back, but not accurately

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm working on Ajax from the last few days, but right now I'm stuck.

I'm trying to send Form data from my client's page to my server through Ajax, the Ajax call works but it doesn't sends the data along with it.

Hear's my server-side program.

```
<?php
$room_name = $_POST['Room_name'];
$room_code = rand(100000,999999);
echo $room_code ; 
echo $room_name ;
?>
```

Basically it just receives the value and generates a 6 didit random no. and prints that .

So, the Ajax response that I get includes the 6 Digit no. but says undefined index for *$room_code* .

Hear's my Ajax script.

```
$("#form1").on('submit' , function(event) {
            var form_data = $("#form1").serialize();
            event.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url : "./process_php/Chat1.php" ,
                data : $('#form1').serialize() ,
                cache : false ,
                processData : false  ,
                //contentType : false ,
                type : "POST" ,


                success : function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    }
                });
        });
```

I've spent hours online searching for my answer, but to no avail.

So any help regarding that would be very helpful for me.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Are you sure, That this key `Room_name` is exist in your serialized form data?

Comment: What does the form you're serializing look like? What does the result of `$('#form1').serialize()` look like?

Comment: How can I verify that?

Comment: *"So, the Ajax response that I get includes the 6 Digit no. but says undefined index for $room_code ."* That doesn't make sense. What is the **exact** response you see (from the Network panel in devtools)?

Comment: @AragAggrawal show us the serialized data also check you are using the correct key name

Comment: I don't know why the serialized data is an empty string!

Comment: @AragAggrawal open the console (f12 - console tab) - and enter `$('#form1').serialize()`

Comment: I opened my console and typed $('#form1').serialize() and the response that I got was " " .

Comment: So how could I fix that!

Comment: Do you have a form with an ID of `form1` which contains your input named `Room_name` as a child element?

Comment: Yes, I have the required form and its child input element!

Comment: Did you type something into the field before running `$('#form1').serialize()` in the console? There's no reason it should appear blank. Go here, enter a value in the field, then click submit and check your console (this is what should happen for you if the input is named and is within your form): https://jsfiddle.net/vtcnbu2w/

Comment: I've checked my console after hitting submit but still, it doesn't work out!

Comment: Did you hit submit on the fiddle I linked, or on your own code? The fiddle should at least produce the result `Room_name=` in your console (if the field is empty). If it produces nothing for you, what browser are you using? I can't imagine why it wouldn't work unless you're using archaic IE versions.

Comment: No, that's not the case, the fiddle that you shared with me worked, but my code isn't working. Right now I'm using the latest version of chromium on Ubuntu.

Comment: You may have to post your HTML form, then. The PHP is just a simple echo of a `$_POST` variable, which looks fine, the jQuery (though you probably don't need `processData: false`) looks like it should work - at the very least running `$('#form1').serialize()` should work with what you've said - so really, the HTML is all that's left to look at.

Comment: @mark.hch Thanks, I've finally done that! In my HTML, the form and a div had the same id, and that's why all of this came into being!

Comment: That would do it. Glad to hear it's resolved now. Good luck with the rest of your development. If you have time, be sure to check out other questions to see if you can help someone else.